# Using global variable inside a python function

Tags: python

So here is the code that uses `x` inside a function.

```
x = 1
def f():
    y = x
    x = 2
    return x + y
print x
print f()
print x
```

but python is not going to look up the variable out of function scope , and it results in `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment` . I am not trying to modify the value of global variable , i just want to use it when i do `y=x`.

On the other hand if i just use it in return statment , it works as expected:

```
x = 1
def f():
  return x
print x
print f()
```

Can some one explain it why?

Comment: problem is not `y = x` but `y = x` with `x = 2` together. Remove one of them and this error disappears.  ( but you may get different :) )

Comment: but `x = 2` is below `y=x` , so i mean python should deal with `y=x` first , assign 1 to y and then on the line `x=2` create a new local variable and assign a value 2 to it. isnt it?

Answer (score 2):

you have to specify `global x` in your function if you want to modify your value, 
however it's not mandatory for just reading the value:

```
x = 1
def f():
    global x
    y = x
    x = 2
    return x + y
print x
print f()
print x
```

outputs

```
1
3
2
```

Comment: i think i am not modifying the value. question updated

Comment: `y = x` , is not modifying `x` , so why i need a `global` keyword here

Comment: @IjazKhan `y = x` is not but `x = 2` is.

Comment: but `x=2` , is meant to assign a new local variable assignment , python will look first at local scope in this case. since the the line `y=x` is above that line  , in that case python should look at global scope and bring the value 1 to y

Comment: @IjazKhan without `global`, python sees `y=x` so it instantiate `y` based on the global `x` since reading global variable is fine. however `x=1` tries to modify the global variable `x` which is forbidden without a `global x`.
The idea behind is that, reading a global variable is harmless so python let's you do it without precaution. However modifying a global variable can have unexpected consequences so python requires you to explicitly say "I want to use the global variable `x` and be able to modify it"

Comment: no , but when i do `x=2` on that i line i mean to create a local variable x , and on `y=x` i mean that python will lookup global variable since it is just a read of global variable.